# 「ハンドルされていない例外が発生しました」の原因が分かりません

Tags: c++, opencv

このエラーの原因がわからないので教えてください. ソースコードは次のとおりです.

[image: エラーウィンドウ]

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
//#ifdef _OPENMP
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Mat img;
    Mat img_copy=img.clone();

    // カメラの起動
    VideoCapture capture("http://192.168.71.98:8080/?action=stream&ignored.mjpg"); 
    capture>>img;
    cvtColor(img,img,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    threshold(img,img,0,255,THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    imshow("bin",img);

    vector<vector<Point>>contours;
    findContours(img,contours,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    vector<vector<Point>> contours_subset;

    for(int i=0;i<contours.size();i++){
            double area=contourArea(contours.at(i));
            printf("%f\n",area);
            if(area>5000&&area<15000){
                contours_subset.push_back(contours.at(i));
            }
    }

    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,CV_8UC1);
    drawContours(mask,contours_subset,-1,Scalar(255),-1);

    Mat result;
    img_copy.copyTo(result,mask);

    imshow("img",img);
    imshow("img_copy",img_copy);
    imshow("mask",mask);
    imshow("result",result);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

//#endif
```

Comment: 編集時にソースコード部分だけ選択して `{}`をクリックすると見やすくハイライトされますので、次回からお試しください。

Comment: プロジェクトのプロパティで、ブラウザ情報の有効化や、デバッグ情報の生成などのオプションをONにしてコンパイルし、デバッガでステップ実行してみてはどうでしょうか？　たぶん今提示されている情報では答えられる人は居ないと思われます。

Comment: `capture`変数でURLを開いた直後の行で、[`isOpened()`関数](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a9d2ca36789e7fcfe7a7be3b328038585)がtrueを返すかを確認してみてください。正しくソース動画を開けていない場合、行列`img`が空(empty)のまま後続処理に突入してC++例外`cv::Exception`が送出されます。